# Matching across Multiple documents with ElasticSearch

Tags: php, search, elasticsearch, ocr

I am relatively new to ElasticSearch. I am using it as a search platform for pdf documents. I break the PDFs into text-pages and enter each one as an elasticSearch record with it's corresponding page ID, parent info, etc.

What I'm finding difficult is matching a given query not only to a single document in ES, but making it match any document with the same parent ID. So if two terms are searched, if the terms existed on page 1 and 7 of the actual PDF document (2 separate entries into ES), I want to match this result.

Essentially my goal is to be able to search through the multiple pages of a single PDF, matching happening on any of the document-pages in the PDF, and to return a list of matching PDF documents for the search result, instead of matching "pages"

Comment: Thanks very much for the answers so far. I wanted to clarify the requirements.

Duc.duong has suggested using has_child, this seems most logical. I wanted to add that I need the ability to determine (perhaps via a secondary query) the pages on which the matches occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's somewhat tricky. First of all, you will have to split your query into terms yourself. Having a list of terms (let's say `foo`, `bar` and `baz`, you can create a bool query against type representing PDFs (parent type) that would look like this:

```
{
    "bool" : {
        "must" : [{
            "has_child" : {
                "type": "page",
                "query": {
                    "match": {
                        "page_body": "foo"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            "has_child" : {
                "type": "page",
                "query": {
                    "match": {
                        "page_body": "bar"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            "has_child" : {
                "type": "page",
                "query": {
                    "match": {
                        "page_body": "baz"
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
   }
}
```

This query will find you all PDFs that contain at least one page with each term.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the "has_child" query on pages. I'm assumed that you're already defined the mapping for parent/child relationship of documents and pages. Then you can write a "has_child" query that search on pages (child type) but return PDF documents (parent type):

```
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "your_pages_type",
      "score_type": "max", // read document for more
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "some text to search",
          "fields": [
            "your_pages_body"
          ],
          "default_operator": "and" // "and" if you want to search all words, "or" if you want to search any of words in query
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, this is very helpful. One functionality I need to preserve is the ability to identify on which page a given word was matched. 

Given that if I use the parent/child mapping, it will return the parent document, is there still a way to retrieve the set of matched pages (children, aka: word matches in this case)?

Comment: I'm afraid that you have to do 2nd query to get matched pages. I've faced this problem and this is what I solved : 1. do a has_child query like my answer to find PDF doc, 2. do a normal query with same condition as has_child to find pages, but limited to parents that have matched in (1) (query + filter). (2) query run very fast because the search is limited in specified parents scope and possible cached before by ES.